# Remove previous marker and marker's info failed

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I am having trouble by my marker because everytime the `Latitude` and `Longitude` changed, it will create a new marker instead of overriding the old one. I am fetching multiple markers so I stored it inside and `ArrayList`.
And also my `String busRoute` and `int passenger` turns to be null. So here's my code. I hope someone can figure out my problem.

```
private String name, busNum, busRoute, currentLocation, estimatedTime, availableSeat, lat, lng;
double latitude, longitude;
int passenger;

public void markerDriver() {
    markerArray = new ArrayList<>();
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_DRIVER);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
                markerInfo();
            } else {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.child("availableSeat").exists() && snapshot.child("latitude").exists() && snapshot.child("longitude").exists() && snapshot.child("estimatedTime").exists()) {
                        name = snapshot.child("driversName").getValue().toString().trim();
                        busNum = snapshot.child("busNum").getValue().toString().trim();
                        lat = snapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString().trim();
                        lng = snapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString().trim();
                        availableSeat = snapshot.child("availableSeat").getValue().toString().trim();
                        estimatedTime = snapshot.child("estimatedTime").getValue().toString().trim();
                        latitude = Double.valueOf(lat);
                        longitude = Double.valueOf(lng);

                        convertLatLong();
                        getTotalPass();
                        markerArray.add(new Driver(name, busNum, busRoute, passenger, latitude, longitude, currentLocation, estimatedTime));
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < markerArray.size(); i++) {
                    createMarker(markerArray.get(i).getDriversName(), markerArray.get(i).getBusNum(), markerArray.get(i).getRoute(), markerArray.get(i).getTotalPassenger(), markerArray.get(i).getLatitude(), markerArray.get(i).getLongitude(), markerArray.get(i).getLocation(), markerArray.get(i).getEstimatedTime());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMapActivity.this, "markerDriver: " + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

public void convertLatLong() {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<android.location.Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null) {
            currentLocation = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        } else {
            currentLocation = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getTotalPass() {
    busRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_BUSNUMBER);
    Query bus = busRef.orderByChild("busNum").equalTo(busNum);
    bus.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                passenger = Integer.valueOf(snapshot.child("capacity").getValue().toString().trim()) - Integer.valueOf(availableSeat);
                busRoute = snapshot.child("route").getValue().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(MainMapActivity.this, "routeGetTotalPass: " + busRoute + ":::" + passenger, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMapActivity.this, "getTotalPass: " + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**createMarker**

```
protected void createMarker(String driversName, final String busNum, String route, final int totalPass, double latitude, double longitude, String location, String estimatedTime) {
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(location)
            .snippet("Driver's Name: " + driversName + "\nBus number: " + busNum + "\nRoute: " + route + "\nTotal Passenger: " + totalPass + "\nEstimated time: " + estimatedTime));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
            dialogInfo(marker);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show your createMarker method as well?

Comment: @ArjunGurung please see my updated question. I already put the createMarker method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare a list of marker 
    `ArrayList<Marker> markerList=new ArrayList<>();`
then change your method create marker to

```
protected void createMarker(String driversName, final String busNum, String route, final int totalPass, double latitude, double longitude, String location, String estimatedTime) {
    boolean isOld = false;
    for (Marker m:markerList) {
        if (m.getTitle().equals(location)) {
            m.setPosition(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            isOld=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isOld) {
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(location)
                .snippet("Driver's Name: " + driversName + "\nBus number: " + busNum + "\nRoute: " + route + "\nTotal Passenger: " + totalPass + "\nEstimated time: " + estimatedTime));
    markerList.add(marker);
    }
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
            dialogInfo(marker);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

this is working for me

Comment: Hi arjun, I am storing a `POJO` on my markerArray. as you can see on the  above codes, I have a POJO model `Driver`

Comment: hi arjun, can you please give me sample code on how to add a data inside that markerList?

Comment: @tin in createMarker method of mine if there is existing marker it will update otherwiese create a new on.Only changing your code with mine will do your work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the old marker before  add new marker

```
                   if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                    } 
                    convertLatLong();
                    getTotalPass();
                    markerArray.add(new Driver(name, busNum, busRoute, passenger, latitude, longitude, currentLocation, estimatedTime));
```

another way is clear GoogleMap before add new marker

```
googleMap.clear();
```

before onCreate declare

Marker marker;

then change

```
 protected void createMarker(String driversName, final String busNum, String route, final int totalPass, double latitude, double longitude, String location, String estimatedTime) {
marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .title(location)
        .snippet("Driver's Name: " + driversName + "\nBus number: " + busNum + "\nRoute: " + route + "\nTotal Passenger: " + totalPass + "\nEstimated time: " + estimatedTime));
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
        dialogInfo(marker);
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I already tried `googleMap.clear();` but returns no marker at all

Comment: In your code every time you create new marker so change Marker marker is global variable

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove particular marker then use weakhash map with integer as id and marker object then you can remove it on the basis of index id.

For more check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35363423/2128166

Answer (score 0):

I made it with the following code:

```
    final WeakHashMap<String,Marker> obj = new WeakHashMap<>();

    mRootRef.child("Coordinates/" + mRequestID)
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Coordinates coordinates = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coordinates.class);
            final String lat = coordinates.getLatitude();
            final String lng = coordinates.getLongitude();

            latLng1 = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(lng));
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng1);


            mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng1, 15));
            mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

            Marker marker = mapa.addMarker( markerOptions);
            marker.setSnippet(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            marker.showInfoWindow();

            // Here is where I create the unique marker identification
            obj.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), marker);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


              Coordinates coordinates = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coordinates.class);
         final String lat = coordinates.getLatitude();
         final String lng = coordinates.getLongitude();

         latLng1 = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(lng));
         markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1);

         // Now, it's just needed to update its new position
         obj.get(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setPosition(latLng1);

         mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng1, 15));
         mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```